# What are these circles on my ceiling?

Tags: water, ceiling, stain

Hoping you may be able to provide some insight. We moved into our current house three years ago and noticed some circles on the ceiling.

[image]  
[image]

[image]

The circles are varying size, feel smooth and dry, and have not gotten any worse in three years. There is a small chunk of missing material in the middle of some circles.

Located in Canada.

Any ideas what caused these? Thank you!

Comment: Were there crops growing there? :D  How big are the circles? Is there any sort of pattern or logic to their arrangement? Are they all in the same room? Maybe give us a drawing of one or two rooms with the circles located (dimensions from the walls).

Answer (score 5):

First and third look like there was a different light fixture there that had two ceiling mounts. The one poking out from under the current light fixture base strongly supports this idea. If the second mount was ONLY for support, it might be fine; if the second mount (first & third picture) had a junction box that is now buried, not so good.

The second picture looks very much like a perfectly circular water stain. Which can happen when perfectly flat drywall got a bit wet in the past. The different colors are diagnostic, and the apparent lack of surface marking is also diagnostic, *.vs.* 1 & 3

Comment: The second stain has just a tiny bit of asymmetry from 9 o'clock to 12 o'clock. Increases the probability of water.